# Error #2032: Stream Error occurring on Fedora but not on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-flex, ubuntu, flex4, flash, fedora

This error has been faced by many people, as seen via internet, but none of the solutions given worked for me.

**Problem:**
I have a flex application which I am trying to run on a Linux machine. On Ubuntu, it works fine but on Fedora following error arises when a login button is clicked.

```
text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://192.168.1.115/flexApp/utils/db_mgmt.php"].
```

**Details:**
Login button actually sends username and password entered by a user to a server deployed on same machine via HTTPService. That HTTPService actually sends data to db_mgmt.php on the server which takes care of authorization of the user by querying mysql database deployed on same machine. I am accessing db_mgmt.php in my code as:

```
_httpS.url= "utils/" + db_mgmt.php;
```

Point here is that I am accessing it via localhost. So I guess, I don't need crossdomain.xml.

**Machines Information:**

- Machine on which App is not working:

  Linux Distro: Fedora
  IP: 192.168.1.115
  App Path: **/var/www/html/flexApp**.
  Owner: **david:david**
  Permissions: **755**
  (I have tried setting permissions to 777 and owner to apache:apache just for testing but that din work either. Btw 'apache' is the user name running Apache/httpd on Fedora.)
- Machine on which App is working fine:

  Linux Distro: Ubuntu
  IP: 192.168.1.113
  App Path: **/var/www/flexApp**.
  Owner: **mark:mark**
  Permissions: **755**.

**Problem seems not related to the Flash Player version:**
I am accessing both machines from a third machine via firefox browser. Ubuntu one works fine. Fedora one returns the error mentioned. Point here is that this problem is not related to the FlashPlayer version I have in my third machine's firefox browser. Had it been the case, same problem should have popped up with the Ubuntu machine. (Note: same problem occurs in Chrome and Internet Explorer)

**Problem is not because of incorrect path:**
I can access following path fine. No problem occurs. And I get output from the file db_mgmt.php on both machines:

> Fedora: http://192.168.1.115/flexApp/utils/db_mgmt.php
>   Ubuntu: http://192.168.1.113/flexApp/utils/db_mgmt.php

**Where do I think the problem can be?**
Well, after going through a lot of forums about this problem and trying the solutions given (with unsuccessful results), only thing i can think of is that some thing is wrong with the permissions of my files on Fedora server. HTTPService on Fedora machine is unable to access db_mgmt.php. But I don't know how can I be sure of it or what can be its solution. Do I need to make some changes to the settings of apache on Fedora machine?

I have to have run this app on Fedora for some other reasons. Hope to find a solution here. :)

Thanks.

**Update:**
Here is the whole dump of the error message:

```
(mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#0
body=""
cliendId = "DirectHTTPChannel0"
correlationId= "CD7D67A8-1AD1-5C89-331B-
07B7E51BC3A0"
  destination = ""
  extendedData = (null)
  faultCode = "Server.Error.Request"
  faultDetail = "Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://192.168.1.115/flexApp/utils/db_mgmt.php"]. URL: http://192.168.1.115/flexApp/utils/db_mgmt.php"
  faultString = "HTTP request error"
  headers = (Object)#1
    DSStatusCode = 500
  messageId = "5D10EE4D-BFA5-201E-EABE-07B7E550F727"
  rootCause = (flash.events::IOErrorEvent)#2
    bubbles = false
    cancelable = false
    currentTarget = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
      bytesLoaded = 0
      bytesTotal = 0
      data = ""
      dataFormat = "text"
    errorID = 0
    eventPhase = 2
    target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
    text = "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://192.168.1.115/flexApp/utils/db_mgmt.php"
    type = "ioError"
  timestamp = 0
```

Comment: have you tried passing the absolute hard-coded path to _httpS.url ?

Comment: Yes. Same error with using absolute hard-coded path. :-/

Comment: I was wrong. db_mgmt.php wasn't displaying right information from database rather it wasn't displaying anything from database. I mistakenly thought that the output getting displayed was from DB. Installing php-mysql solved the problem. Man! I wasted so much time on this. Anyways, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

First guess: your [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) configuration isn't correctly set for your application. Fedora ships with SELinux and Ubuntu ships with [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), so the MAC frameworks you're using are vastly different on the different systems.

Check your `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `/var/log/messages` for `avc:denied` messages. See the [Fedora SELinux FAQ](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux_FAQ#How_do_I_find_out_whether_SELinux_is_denying_access_for_any_software.3F) for suggestions on how to *really* work with SELinux properly. Just a guess that the security context of your `db_mgmt.php` might not be properly set. Check `ls -Z` output on the `db_mgmt.php` file and compare it against other *working* PHP scripts -- perhaps you just need to update the security context to something the PHP interpreter domain can access.

Second guess: your server isn't configured to listen on the publicly accessible IP address `192.168.1.115` on the Fedora machine. Check `netstat -anp` output to make sure that the web server serving your application is listening to `0.0.0.0:80`, not `127.0.0.1:80`.

Third guess: See if *any* applications allow you to communicate "locally" via the hardware interface's address. (Check `ssh 192.168.1.115` against `ssh 127.0.0.1` and make sure *both* work. See `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/accept_local` documentation in the Linux kernel source `Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt`.)

Comment: My SELinux is disabled. ls -Z returns same output for all php files i.e. (-rw-rw-r-- david:david unlabeled db_mgmt.php). On Ubuntu, however it returns: '? db_mgmt.php' for all php files. `netstat -anp | grep httpd` returns "tcp  0  0 :::80  :::*  LISTEN  5107/httpd". This seems fine too. SSH with both IPs is working too. :)

Comment: I was wrong. db_mgmt.php wasn't displaying right information from database rather it wasn't displaying anything from database. I mistakenly thought that the output getting displayed was from DB. Installing php-mysql solved the problem. Man! I wasted so much time on this. Anyways, thank you. :)

Comment: Don't forget to post the actual solution as an answer, to save someone else the trouble in the future!